# behavior of functions with parameters inside arguments

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, conditional

I don't understand this behavior: why does `Limit[z/(z - a), z -> 0]` give zero and not a condition depending on `a`, provided it has not been defined before? is there a way to make it work properly? (By working properly I mean give the correct result, namely 1 if $a=0$ and 0 otherwise.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GeneratingConditions` option so MMA can look for conditionals:

```
Limit[z/(z - a), z -> 0, GenerateConditions -> True]

(* ConditionalExpression[0, a != 0] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Would something similar also work for Residue function, namely Residue[1/(z-a),{z,0}] ?

Comment: No, only some functions accept `GeneratingConditions` as an option, and `Residue` is not one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, with the assumptions Mathematica uses for `a`, the value of it does not matter for the residue or the limit. Here are two counter-examples:

```
Residue[Gamma[z] Gamma[z - 1] Gamma[z - a], {z, 0}]
(* -Gamma[-a] + 2 EulerGamma Gamma[-a] - 
 Gamma[-a] PolyGamma[0, -a] *)
```

and

```
Limit[z^a, z -> 0]
(* ConditionalExpression[0, a > 0] *)
```

Comment: The assumptions Mathematica makes are given in the conditional expression if there is one. Can you make clear in your question what you mean by "make it work properly"? What output would you expect from `Limit[z/(z-a), z->0]`?

Comment: I'm not sure how Mathematica handles this. This here works though `Limit[z/(z - a), z -> 0, Assumptions -> a == 0]`

Comment: I would regard this as a bug. See  `Limit[z/(z - a), z -> 0, Assumptions -> -1 < a < 1]` gives `(*  0  *) `